# How do I send channels 2.x group message from django-celery 3 task?

Tags: django, redis, django-celery, django-channels

I need to postpone sending channels message. Here is my code:

```
# consumers.py
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def chat_message(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event['message']))

    def connect(self):
        self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_name, self.channel_name)
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        send_message_task.apply_async(
            args=(
                self.room_name,
                {'type': 'chat_message',
                 'message': 'the message'}
            ),
            countdown=10
        )

# tasks.py
@shared_task
def send_message_task(room_name, message):
    layer = get_channel_layer()
    layer.group_send(room_name, message)
```

The task is being executed and I can't see any errors but message is not being sent. It works only if I send it from consumer class method.

I also tried using AsyncWebsocketConsumer and sending with AsyncToSync(layer.group_send). It errors with "You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly."

Then I tried declaring send_message_task as async and using await. Nothing happens again (with no errors) and I'm not sure if the task is executed at all.

Here are versions:

```
Django==1.11.13
redis==2.10.5
django-celery==3.2.2
channels==2.1.2
channels_redis==2.2.1
```

Settings:

```
REDIS_HOST = os.getenv('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1')
BROKER_URL = 'redis://{}:6379/0'.format(REDIS_HOST)
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": ['redis://{}:6379/1'.format(REDIS_HOST)],
        },
    },
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPD:** Just found out that redis channel layer is retreived but it's group_send method is not called and just skipped.

**UPD 2:** Sending using `AsyncToSync(layer.group_send)` from console works. Calling task without `apply_async` also works. But running it with `apply_async` causes an error `You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly`. Defining task as async and using `await` also breaks everything of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is not direct answer to a starting question but this might help.
If you get exception "You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly" then you probably makes some of this:

1. event loop is created somewhere
2. some ASYNC code is started
3. some SYNC code is called from ASYNC code
4. SYNC code is trying to call ASYNC code with AsyncToSync that prevents this

Seems that AsyncToSync detects outer event loop and makes decision to not interfere with it.

Solution is to directly include your async call in outer event loop.
Example code is below, but best is to check your situation and that outer loop is running ...

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(layer.group_send(room_name, {'type': 'chat_message', 'message': message}))
```

Comment: ' best is to check your situation and that outer loop is running ...' how to do this?? My problem is that everything works perfect but when request are increased it throws this error

Answer (score 2):

You need the `async_to_sync()` wrapper on connect when using channel layers because all channel layer methods are asynchronous.

```
def connect(self):
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_name, self.channel_name)
    self.accept()
```

Same deal with sending the message from your celery task.

```
@shared_task
def send_message_task(room_name, message):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        room_name,
        {'type': 'chat_message', 'message': message}
    )
```

Also you can just call your celery task from your consumer's `receive()` like this:

```
send_message_task.delay(self.room_name, 'your message here')
```

Regarding the AsyncToSync error you need to upgrade channels and daphne to a newer version as [explained in this thread](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1017).

Comment: The task is already being called from `receive()` and I already tried using `async_to_sync()`. As I said in queestion, it errors with "You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly."

Comment: Updated my answer - you'll need to upgrade to the new version of channels and daphne

Comment: They are of newest versions. channels==2.1.2, daphne==2.2.0, asgiref==2.3.2

Answer (score 2):

I found an ugly and inefficient decision, but it works:

```
@shared_task
def send_message_task(room_name, message):
    def sender(room_name, message):
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

        AsyncToSync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            room_name,
            {'type': 'chat_message', 'message': message}
        )

    thread = threading.Thread(target=sender, args=(room_name, message,))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

If someone can improve it, I will appreciate.

Comment: Why are you trying so hard to avoid async. Make an async function and run it in the event loop in send_message_task.

Comment: You mean make `sender` async? I tried, it doesn't work. Same problem as just calling `group_send` from the task directly.

Comment: You cant make send_message_task async but you could make sender async. Get the thread's event loop and run it with create_task or run_until_complete if you want to block. Then remove AsyncToSync and await group_send directly.

Comment: Only right way here is to use AsyncToSync. But the core of this problem with in celery task is seems that in celery you have some outer event loop when your sync code in task in run. Then channel_layer thinks that it has been called from async code and prevent this call. Strange that there is no sync version of channel_layer for this situations ...

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is that you used `underscore` in your type `chat_message`.  I believe you missed it in the documentation:

> The name of the method will be the type of the event with periods
>   replaced by underscores - so, for example, an event coming in over the
>   channel layer with a type of `chat.join` will be handled by the method
>   `chat_join`.

So in your case, the type will be `chat.message`

```
{
    'type': 'chat.message',
    'message': 'the message'
}
```

Comment: Just tried. No difference. And it works with chat_message from consumer class method. I guess the problem is that there is no consumer class instance in task so it can't find the method. I tried creating it and sending using it's method. Doesn't help also. Have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, I have tried implementing it in tasks already and it works fine, my celery version is 4.1.0, the only thing that differs is that I am using `AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer`, but your consumer should work fine.  I can't see another error from your code except the one I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's very strange. Just found out that redis channel layer is retreived but it's group_send method is not called and just skipped.

Comment: Have you tried manually calling `layer.group_send(room_name, message)` in your terminal? maybe in django shell?

Comment: It returns <coroutine object RedisChannelLayer.group_send at 0x05A558D0> and doesn't send anything.