# Django Channels send group message from Celery task. Asyncio event loop stopping before all async tasks finished

Tags: django, celery, gevent, channel, python-3.7

I'm currently stuck on a particularly tricky problem, I'll try my best to explain it.

I have a Django project and it's main purpose is to execute queued tasks from a DB rapidly. I use Celery and Celerybeat to achieve this with Django channels to update my templates with the responses in real time.

The Celery worker is a gevent worker pool with a decent number of threads.

My Task(Simplified version):

```
@shared_task
def exec_task(action_id):
  # execute the action
  action = Action.objects.get(pk=action_id)
  response = post_request(action)

  # update action status
  if response.status_code == 200:
    action.status = 'completed'

  else:
    action.status = 'failed'

  # save the action to the DB
  action.save()

  channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
  status_data = {'id': action.id, 'status': action.status}
  status_data = json.dumps(status_data)
  try:
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)('channel_group', {'type': 'propergate_status', 'data': status_data})
  except:
    event_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(channel_layer.group_send('channel_group', {'type': 'propergate_status', 'data': status_data}), event_loop)
    result = future.result()
```

My Error:

> [2019-10-03 18:47:59,990: WARNING/MainProcess] actions queued: 25
>
> [2019-10-03 18:48:02,206: WARNING/MainProcess]
>   c:\users\jack\documents\github\mcr-admin\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent_socket3.py:123:
>   RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncToSync.main_wrap' was never awaited
>   self._read_event = io_class(fileno, 1)
>
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
>
> [2019-10-03 18:48:02,212: WARNING/MainProcess] c:\users\jack\documents\github\mcr-admin\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent_socket3.py:123:
>   RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseEventLoop.shutdown_asyncgens' was never
>   awaited   self._read_event = io_class(fileno, 1) RuntimeWarning:

Originally after I saved the action to the DB I just called:

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)('channel_group', {'type': 'propergate_status', 'data': status_data})
```

But I kept getting a runtime error because you can't use *async_to_sync* if there is already an *asyncio* event loop already running, [as shown here at line 61](https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/master/asgiref/sync.py). So I had multiple *gevent* threads trying to *async_to_sync* very close together, constantly throwing the error in the link.

Which led me to [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53544010/11467338) and the current version of the *exec_task* which has a 98% success rate in messaging the Django Channels group but I really need it to be 100%.

The problem here is that occasionally the asyncio event loop is stopped before the Coroutine I add has a chance to finish and I've been tweaking my code, playing around with the asyncio and event loop api but I either break my code or get worse results. I have a feeling it might be to do with the [Asgiref](https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/master/asgiref/sync.py) *async_to_sync* function closing the loop early but it's complex and I only started working with python async a couple of days ago.

Any feedback, comments, tips or fixes are most welcome!

Cheers.

Comment: You should use `except RunetimeError:` so that you don't accidentally silence other errors you might get.

Comment: Thanks I added in the `except RuntimeError:`, sadly there was no change in logs.

Comment: I didn't think it would fix your problem, but it will at least save you from a potential debugging nightmare in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I couldn't solve the problem and choose an alternative solution using a Channels *AsyncHttpConsumer* to send the group message. It's not optimal but it works and keeps the workflow in the Channels library.

Consumer:

```
class celeryMessageConsumer(AsyncHttpConsumer):

async def handle(self, body):
    # send response
    await self.send_response(200, b"Recieved Loud and Clear", headers=[
        (b"Content-Type", b"text/plain"),
    ])
    # formating url encoded string into json
    body_data = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(body.decode("utf-8"))
    body_data = json.loads(body_data)
    id = body_data['data']['id']

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        f"group_{id}",
        {
            'type': 'propergate.data',
            'data': body_data['data']
        }
    )
```

Routing:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            myApp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
    'http': URLRouter([
        path("celeryToTemplate/", consumers.celeryMessageConsumer),
        re_path('genericMyAppPath/.*', AsgiHandler),
    ]),
})
```

Http Request:

```
data = json.dumps({'id': id, 'status': status})
response = internal_post_request('http://genericAddress/celeryToTemplate/', data)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # phew
    pass
else:
    # whoops
    pass
```

Requests:

```
def internal_post_request(request_url, payload):
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.post(request_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i'm currently encountering your exact issue where it's critical to be able to send messages from completed celery tasks to the client.

I was able to group_send before by using a signal to a model method for example:

```
def SyncLogger(**kwargs):
    """ a syncronous function to instigate the websocket layer
    to send messages to all clients in the project """

instance = kwargs.get('instance')
# print('instance {}'.format(instance))

args = eval(instance.args)
channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
    args ['room'],
    {
        "type": "chat.message",
        "operation": args['operation'],
        "state": instance.state,
        "task": instance.task
    })
```

and the signal

```
post_save.connect(SyncLogger, TaskProgress)
```

**Update**
I was able to send messages as long as there's an `event_loop`
this works no matter whether the consumer is async or not

```
@shared_task()
def test_message():
   channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

   loop.run_until_complete(channel_layer.group_send('sync_chat', {
       'type': 'chat.message',
       'operation': 'operation',
       'state': 'state',
       'task': 'task'
   }))
```

Comment: Hi, in the end I couldn't solve the problem and used an alternative solution. I used a Channels *AsyncHttpConsumer* to send the group message. I'll post my alternative solution.

Comment: It's possible to use both sync and async consumers as long as there's an event loop and calling it's `run_until_complete` method

Comment: Cheers for the update I'm glad you got it working. Sadly I've already tried creating/manipulating the asyncio loop. I did try your updated solution but ran into expected problems chiefly being my worker pool Gevent. Although hopefully your solution will be of help to others.

Comment: Sorry, in attempt to better understand what is your issue? could you share the error message? it's the 1st time i've used asyncio

Comment: I won't recreate the error because that takes time and means modifying my code. I'm running a Celery gevent worker with a concurrency of 10 green threads. I have 10 greenlets running inside a single thread. When I create a _Asyncio_ event loop in one greenlet it's created for the entire thread, all 10 greenlets have access to the same _Asyncio_ event loop. Often I have a large amount of tasks scheduled to be processed simultaneously. When multiple greenlets call _AsyncToSync_ simultaneously the error occurs [here at line 61](https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/master/asgiref/sync.py#L61).